# How do I reset my Windows 7 password with a flash drive?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, password-recovery

My laptop was installed with Windows 7 with only one account, but no reset disk was created. Now I had forgotten my password and don't know how to reset it.

Had tried [OPH Crack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) to burn its ISO into a flash drive, but failed to boot my laptop. Is there any way to reset my password without formatting my whole system disk?

Comment: Take a look at this [SU blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/03/01/kon-boot-getting-into-a-clients-computer-without-using-a-portal-gun/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use [NT password recovery](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) with [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to bring NT password recovery to a USB drive. You can then boot from USB and reset or delete any user password.

YUMI is very easy to use. Just download YUMI and the ISO, start YUMI and select your USB drive (you have to check "Show ALL Drives? (USE CAUTION)" if you're using a USB HDD), boot from USB and follow the menu in NT password recovery.

If you've problems with NT password recovery, you can check their website for more information on usage or ask here.

*Update:*
If you're not sure which ISO file to download, use YUMI to find out.
YUMI helps you to find the right download and even directs you to the download.
Just search for `Offline NT Password & Registry Editor` and check the `Download the zip (Optional)` checkbox next to the list:

[image: YUMI menu]

As you can see, YUMI also shows the file name below the list painted red because the ISO file isn't yet in my download dir. It'll change that text color to green if when it found the right ISO file in your download dir.

Comment: Thanks @wullxz. Yes YUMI is easy to use, however, I don't know which ISO should I choose to delete my password. Just found that [OPH Crack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) I mentioned in my post can only _recover_ password, it failed to work at my password maybe because it is a little complex.

Comment: YUMI helps you at this point. Have a look at my answer again, I added information regarding your question.