# Windows 10 password reset after update

Tags: windows-7, passwords, windows-10-upgrade, password-recovery

I updated to windows 10 from windows 7 and can't log in to my account. So I forgot my windows 7 password long time ago and have been using fingerprint login ever since on my HP Elitebook.

I was expecting this to cause a problem when upgrading to 10, so I activated the administrator account in windows 7 and made sure that I could log in with that before I started the windows 10 upgrade. During upgrade, I had to uninstall the HP safety and security tools, which means no fingerprint sign in. I thought it would be ok since I now at least could log in to the administrator.

But after upgrade when I tried to log in as administrator it only says user account not active. Thus I can now not log in to my pc as admin or to my normal account for which I forgot my password. Also I don't have password reset disc. Any idea how to gain access to my pc?

Comment: Can you make a bootable disc or usb? if so I can point you to a way to reset your password.

Comment: Have you tried this? - [How do I reset my Windows 7 password with a flash drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/453300/how-do-i-reset-my-windows-7-password-with-a-flash-drive) From the linked question: *My laptop was installed with Windows 7 with only one account, but no reset disk was created. Now I had forgotten my password and I don't know how to reset it.*

Comment: The easiest way and it works for windows 7,8,8.1,and 10 is follow this guide really easy to reset the password. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/) and no reverting or losing anything.

Comment: [All you have to do is enable the Administrator account](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)

Answer (score 0):

With the link by @NetworkKingPin and a little assistance from this youtube video I managed to get it working.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBd23RqViA0

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgaup.jpg), you should be able to activate the administrator by following these steps:

> 1. Boot from Windows installation CD.
> 2. When comes to Windows Setup screen, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open Command Prompt.
> 3. At the Command Prompt, replace `sethc.exe` with `cmd.exe` by running this command:
>
>    `copy c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe c:\ copy /y
>      c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe`
> 4. Exit Windows Setup and reboot. When you get back to Windows login screen, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> five times to launch Command Prompt.
> 5. Type the following command to activate the administrator account:
>
>    `net user administrator /active:yes`
> 6. Reboot and you should be able to login. After getting into Windows, remember to restore the sethc.exe back to the directory
>      c:\windows\system32.

Comment: Will `sethc.exe` be restored automatically after a while? I don't think so. Anyone using this hack may consider renaming it before overwriting, then restoring at the very end to close the security gap.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.