# How to take a screenshot when not signed in?

Tags: windows, windows-10, screenshot

Is it possible to take a screenshot in Windows (10) when not signed in to a user - (I.e. user select/sign-in screen, kernel panic, etc.)?  In such situations the clipboard is inaccessible so the print screen button doesnt work.

*For instance: I have an error message which comes up after a particular user logs out.  I would like to be able to screenshot this error message.*

Comment: It would be nice to know the DV reason so I can improve.

Comment: Screenshot at the login screen sounds possible using third party tools like jing but screenshot during BSOD seems only possible through VM

Comment: You could remote in to the computer using remote desktop connection and screenshot it that way, but that might not work. I just tried to do a loop back through remote desktop and you can only have one session active at a time, so that won't work. Couldn't you just take a picture of the screen?

Comment: There is a hack described [here](http://superuser.com/a/1083123/432690) to run a command prompt when not signed in. Maybe you could use this with a screenshot program instead. The first step there is to boot from CD/DVD but I think in your case you can shuffle `exe` files during normal work.

Comment: The best thing you can do here is just photograph the screen. Nowadays everyone has a camera on their phone, and the beauty of this solution is, that it also works outside of windows. The photo can easily be sent by email or be moved to the computer through an USB cable.

Comment: @LPChip  That's my solution so far, but I'm looking for something a little less ugly.  Plus the error situation mentioned above is just an example.